# How to access marker object through it's id in Angular-Google-Map?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I want to access **marker** object through it's id. I want to move maker to new position based on change latitude and longitude. This latitude and longitude is define in form, and I added `ng-change="changePosition()"` when anybody change the **latitude** and **longitude**, marker should move, I know the marker id, how to access marker object through it.

```
$scope.changePosition= function(){         
        var latitude=$scope.latitude;
        var longitude=$scope.longitude;
        var marker_id =$scope.id; //Marker_id
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        //Now I want to access marker object using marker_id, 
        marker_obj.setPosition(latlng);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a structure of all the markers, keyed on the ids.

```
var markers = {};
```

Add the markers into here when you create them:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});

markers[marker_id] = marker;
```

Then access it again:

```
marker_obj = markers[marker_id];
marker_obj.setPosition(latlng);
```